# exect fetch result error on oracle report

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

hi dear all i have a formula which check gazetted  dates from a table then provide description its fine if its in between dates only 1 gazetted date comes otherwise it throw error exact fetch I know there is more rows then fetch how i can over come on this please help me
my code is

```
function CF_WEEKRESTFormula return CHAR is
descr      varchar2(90);
gz_dt      date;

begin

select gazzeted_date, description into gz_dt, descr 
  from gazzeted_days

    where   gazzeted_date between :DATE1 and :DATE2;
    :ATT_DATE = GZ_DT THEN 

RETURN DESCR;
```

it have other code mean else and exception conditions all settled only this part is doing wrong I know what mean of this it bring more results than 1 but how to overcome on this is just a problem so tired doing this if any one come forward for help lot of  appreciated
full code is

```
function CF_WEEKRESTFormula return CHAR is
v_rest     number;
gaz_dt     number;
descr      varchar2(90);
gz_dt      date;
AT_P             VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  SELECT week_rest
  INTO   v_rest
  FROM   EMPLOYEES
  WHERE  employee_id1=:employee_id1
  AND    :ATT_DATE between :DATE1 and :DATE2;
  select gazzeted_date, description into gz_dt, descr 
  from gazzeted_days
  where  
         gazzeted_date between :DATE1 and :DATE2;

  
   IF TO_CHAR( :ATT_DATE, 'D' ) = v_rest THEN
    RETURN 'WEEK REST';
  ELSIF
    :ATT_DATE = GZ_DT THEN 
    RETURN DESCR;
  
    ELSE RETURN 'PRESENT';
  END IF;
  exception 
       when No_data_found 
         then return 'NO DATA FOUND';
  END;
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the whole code for the function ...?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan no but this code creating problem other are working fine when i run separately

Comment: this code is incomplete, and will not work if it's as appeared here. Btw, you seem to need more criteria, which we don't know, in order to return only one row from the query. Perhaps you might add an analytic function such as `ROW_NUMBER()`, and then restrict to pick only one record.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I edited the code full

Comment: there's also `too_many_rows` exception to be added, but what do you want to get whenever this occurs?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I have a attendance report I want when gazt dates comes it shows there descr as against dates where dates comes of gazetted date if in gazetted table match 1 holyday than it brings data if more then throw error of exact fetch

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan where to add this please `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: You can [check out](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5boracle%5d%20ROW_NUMBER)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan `ROW_NUMBER()` not worked for me any other solution if you have please :(

Comment: When you run that SELECT statement separately (in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer) and when it returns more than a single row, which values does it return? What would you want to do in that case? Please, post an example.

Comment: @Littlefoot in sql i will use for this cursor to show all data

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't understand the question. That SELECT returns two or more rows, while it is expected that it returns only one. So: what do you want to do in such a case? **Also**, to me it looks as if you should have moved all that code into report's main query, join all tables involved and display data.

Comment: @Littlefoot i want all returned values to be displayed